# Retrieving the very last revision of all posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wiki

I am creating a kind of Wiki using Wordpress. How do I show my users the latest change/revision of all articles?

It should be something like [this](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special%3aRecentChanges), but much simpler: I only need the name of the article and the person who made the change

Comment: I know I can get the revision of a particular post, but I'm looking for a more efficient way than iterating and sorting over all posts to get the latest N post revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, hope it is helpful:

Put this code at starting of your template.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$postData = query_posts('category_name='.$slug.'&post_status=publish,future&showposts=5&paged='.$paged.'&orderby=modified');
```

Thanks.

Comment: what I'm looking for! thanks for telling me the orderby=modified clause

Answer (score 0):

Or try with this links:

[For working with modified date] : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_modified_date

[For working with modified time] : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_modified_time

Thanks.